# Phase correlation char

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm trying to detect chars from a text in white and black. At the moment, the text is a white background with only a few chars in black. Also I've created some little images containing only a char each one. I want to use phase correlation to detect the chars in the initial text. For this I've done:

```
image = im2double(imread("text.png"));
si = size(image);

trans = fft2(image);

ch = im2double(imread("a.bmp"));
chtrans =  fft2(ch,si(1),si(2));        

outt = angle(trans).*conj(angle(chtrans));

outt = abs(ifft2(outt)).^2;
```

When I normalize my outt variable I detect for example all "a" in my text but the image is double: there's the correct result but there's also the correct result flipped, both on the same final image. What's wrong with this?

Comment: Can you post some images to show what you mean?

Comment: Here is the final image:

http://img403.imageshack.us/img403/5256/problemau.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feeding the angle back into the IFFT does not isolate the phase.  You want a complex number with the same angle, but with a magnitude of 1.  You *don't* want a real number that represents the angle.  One way to express phase correlation is to normalize the result of the conjugate multiplication:

```
outt = trans.*conj(chtrans);
outt = outt ./ abs(outt);
outt = real(ifft2(outt));
```

There are other ways to express it, but in any case, the mirror image goes away.  One thing to keep in mind is that your result should ideally be pure real.  Any imaginary components are due to round-off error.  If you find you need to do abs() on the result, you probably did something wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was using only the phase because I have read a document where I understood that they did all process with amplitude=1 because they have better results. Maybe for check if whole image is equal (ex: 2 chars) works well but in this case no.

Comment: Oh! one more thing! If abs(outt) has a 0, which is the best mode to prevent it? adding 0.0000001 to abs before divide?

Comment: Probably handle it directly:  `a = trans.*conj(chtrans);`  `z = (a==0);  a(z) = 1;  outt = a ./ abs(a);  outt(z) = 0;`  That keeps outt zero where it started out as zero.  Also note that this normalizing keeps the amplitude = 1 exactly as you describe... it's only the angle() call that messes up the process.

Answer (score 1):

It's a feature of the Fourier transform--it will detect both positive and negative frequency components; you can ignore the negative parts if you like.

Comment: I've added this after doing ifft2 but before getting abs so I can erase negative numbers from my final image:

extra = real(outt)>= 0;
outt = real(outt).*extra+ imag(outt).*extra;

With this code Extra is a matrix with ones if the value of outt was >=0 or 0 if it was < 0. The result is the same. It's still wrong.